# Downscaled sprites fail to use setPosition()

Tags: android, andengine

I have a 100x100 pixel sprite that i add with `new Sprite(0, 0, mTexture);` and it gets located in the top left corner. So far so good. Then I run `setScale(0.5f);` and it scales down to half in its center and it's no longer in the top left corner, so I issue `setPosition(0, 0);` but it doesn't move.

How do you move the "hot spot" on the sprite after downscaling? Upscaling doesn't seem to have this problem.

(GLES1)

[image: Sprite position after downscale and setPosition(0,0)]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set scaleCenter before scaling:

```
entity.setScaleCenter(0,0);
entety.setScale(0.5f);
```